# How to get gateway interface up in rdo openstack?

Tags: openstack

After configuring rdo openstack to work with external network,the gateway interface of router to the external network is down.
Because of this problem I am access unable to access internet in instances attached to internal network.

Comment: Have you attached public-network to the router? When you connect router to public network(set gateway on router), it gets an ip-address in public subnet. Are you able to ping internal-network's gateway, router's gateway from within the instance?

Comment: Yes I have attached router to public network,it is also getting ip on public network ,but its status is down.Yes I am able to ping internal networks gateway.

Comment: Sir,I am able to ping public networks router from external and internal network's gateway from internal node.But I am unable to access internet in instance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the status of the gateway interface is misleading. The gateway interface of router is marked as DOWN, as it not connected to any VM. Neutron marks a port to be active only when it is connected to some VM.

Troubleshooting steps:
- ping the gateway interface address from an external address. If this does not work, then your external network is not setup right. Check if your external network has the attribute "router:external" set to True:

```
root@openstack-controller:~# neutron net-show ext-net
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                     | Value                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up            | True                                 |
| id                        | b13547a0-cef5-4a25-a00e-d630345f365b |
| mtu                       |                                      |
| name                      | ext-net                              |
| provider:network_type     | vlan                                 |
| provider:physical_network | physnet1                             |
| provider:segmentation_id  | 405                                  |
| router:external           | True                                 |
| shared                    | False                                |
| status                    | ACTIVE                               |
| subnets                   | 526f8ed0-48b0-4e94-bf34-61b51db75bda |
| tenant_id                 | f7e9ac7a7b0643c39af9fcc72c8cc40b     |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```